# Download java applet from webpage

Tags: java, applet

Is there any way to download an applet embedded in a webpage of a site www.abc.com<sup>1</sup>, to one's system?

Or is it possible to extract its code for offline use?

1. E.G. http://www.falstad.com/dotproduct/

Comment: For the link provided, I see the link "Zip archive of this applet.". It contains the applet jar, html page and the java source file!. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the link provided, I see the link "Zip archive of this applet.". It contains the applet jar, html page and the java source file.

Comment: Look at the applet tag in the web page source. The applet class file is located at hagaregn.org.uk/npsudoku/executables/SudokuApplet17.class

Answer (score 3):

You can try to inspect the page source to see the archive file it is using.  In this case, it appears as if it is using http://www.falstad.com/dotproduct/dotproduct.jar.  You can use this in a project, but the source will not be attached.

Answer (score 2):

The applet at http://www.falstad.com/dotproduct/ can certainly be used off-line.  I tested it just to make sure.

You would need to download the `dotproduct.jar` (referenced in the page - are you familiar with "View Source"?) to the local file-system then create an HTML (or use a copy of Paul Falstad's own HTML) to launch it.

You might try "Save page as" for the 2<sup>nd</sup> part, but I am not confident that that would also download the Jar of the applet itself.

Of course, it would be courteous to let Paul know what you are doing.  You *might* find he will be prepared to send you a Zip of the HTML/applet.